# obtain transition matrix in R, depmixS4 package

Tags: r, hidden-markov-models

I formulated a 2-states HMM by using the *depmix()* and *fit()* from the depmixS$ package and got an depmix.fitted object which shows me the transition probability matrix by using *summary()*.
Is there any possibility to extract the transition probability matrix and save it as an vector? *summary(model, which = "transition")* does not work...

The probably easiest solution I found is the following:

```
{a<-(depmix.fitted class)@transition[[1]]@parameters$coefficients
b<-(depmix.fitted class)@transition[[2]]@parameters$coefficients 

transmat<-matrix(data= c(a,b), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE) #combine transition probabilities to the transition probabilities matrix }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the transition probability matrix and save it as a vector using the function `getpars()`:

```
getpars(depmix.fitted)[3:6]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a call to get the posterior probabilities. 
For example this is the code i ran

```
  hmm <- depmix(returns ~ 1, family = gaussian(), nstates = 2, data=data.frame(returns=returns))
  hmmfit <- fit(hmm)
  post_probs <- posterior(hmmfit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining your suggestion with that of Irina Telina, and extending it for multiple states, you can use the following (ignore first lines to create data frame):

```
df_test<-setNames(data.frame(rnorm(100,mean=rnorm(1),sd=runif(1))),"returns")
numk<-5
for (i in 1:numk-1){
  df_test<-rbind(df_test,setNames(data.frame(rnorm(100,mean=rnorm(1),sd=runif(1))),
                                  "returns"))
}
hmm <- depmix(returns ~ 1, family = gaussian(), nstates = numk, data=df_test)
hmmfit <- fit(hmm)
trmat<-matrix(getpars(hmmfit)[(nstates(hmmfit)+1):(nstates(hmmfit)^2+nstates(hmmfit))],
              byrow=TRUE,nrow=nstates(hmmfit),ncol=nstates(hmmfit))
```